# DJANGO REST Framework - API call returns only 20 entities out of many more fetched

Tags: django, rest, api, frameworks, truncate

Django 1.11.3 , python 3.6, coreapi 2.3.3

I execute an API call to my website code from the client.

`listProducts = self.amyClient.getProducts()`
which calls:
       `results = self.client.action(schema, ["products", "list"])`

On the website side it executes `queryset = Product.objects.all()`, no filters.

In `get_queryset` method `len(queryset)` before `return queryset` gives me 52 entries.

On the client side `len(listProduct)` is 20. I added couple of entries just to see what happens - in the API call the quantity of the returned entities changes (so it's not a "connecting to a wrong DB" issue), on the client side it's always 20. 
In the API call `results['count']` is 52, `len(results['results'])` is 20.

Casting queryset to list ( i.e . `queryset = list(Product.Objects.all())`) does not change anything, and I don't really expect it to, just because in the API call code it's correct already. Something must be truncating it on the receiving (client) side. What? Thanks.

My view:

```
class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsBotOrReadOnly,)

    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """

    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    schema = AutoSchema(
        manual_fields=[
            coreapi.Field("productcode"),
        ]
    )


    def get_queryset(self):


        productcode = self.request.query_params.get('productcode', None)

        queryset = Product.active.all()

        if productcode is not None:
            queryset = list(Product.active.filter(productcode=productcode))
        else:
            queryset = Product.active.all()
        # prints 52
        print (len(queryset))
        return queryset
```

Comment: @Alasdair Django 1.11.3, corrected. Also added the key values in results. Yes, it's probably pagination , but how to get rid of it?

Comment: @Alasdair added the view

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the output sent back to client is truncated by the framework by this setting in `settings.py` (server side):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    .......
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20,
    .......
}
```

I really wonder why this is the default behaviour and why the default value is whopping 20 :-) .

Thanks to @Alasdair or pointing me to the paging documentation.